# PHP switch case $_GET's variables and switch case $_GET's variable's values

Tags: php, get, switch-statement

Say I have an URL like `www.mysite.com/index.php?login=0`. Is it possible to switch case $_GET's variables and switch case $_GET's variable's values?

Something like:

```
switch ($_GET) {
    case 'login' :
        switch($_GET['login']) {
            case '0' :
                echo 'Login failed!';
                break;
            case '1' :
                echo 'Login successful.';
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 'register' :
        switch ($_GET['register']) {
            case '0' :
                echo 'Registration failed!';
                break;
            case '1' :
                echo 'Thank you for registering.';
                break;
        }
        break;
    default :
        echo 'Some other message';
        break;
}
```

I'm not sure if switch case can be used on associative arrays. What am I doing wrong? Cheers!

Comment: I improved my answer based on a comment.

Comment: As long as you use switch-case for all your values, your code is also very secure, since you never use any of the user provided values directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to enclose the switch in a foreach() loop.

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'login' :
            switch ($value) {
                case '0' :
                    echo 'Login failed!';
                    break;
                case '1' :
                    echo 'Login successful.';
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 'register' :
            switch ($value) {
                case '0' :
                    echo 'Registration failed!';
                    break;
                case '1' :
                    echo 'Thank you for registering.';
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default :
            echo 'Some other message';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 But you can change `switch($_GET['login'])` and the like to just `switch($value)`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it will work like this, $_get will return an array and these comparisons will not work. Switch statements need to evaluate to a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone nowadays **using at least PHP8**. You can make the code shorter and more concise using the **match** expression:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo match ($key) {
        'login' => match ($value) {
            '0' => 'Login failed!',
            '1' => 'Login successful.',
            default => 'Some other login message',
        },
        'register' => match ($value) {
            '0' => 'Registration failed!',
            '1' => 'Thank you for registering.',
            default => 'Some other register message',
        },
        default => 'Some other message',
    };
}
```

This code uses the match expression, which was introduced in PHP 8, to simplify the nested switch statements. The match expression returns the value of the matching case directly.

Answer (score -2):

Just Use this:

```
switch($_GET['key']) //it will return you value of particular parameter.
case 'value1':
//write your statement here.
break;
case 'value2':
//write your statement here.
break;
//and so on
```