# PHP - an easy way to do this?

Tags: php

I'm new to php. I'll have to repeat this 50 times, so I hope there is an easy way.
Is there an easy way to do this?

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['Arbejdsmiljoudvalget'])){
    $Arbejdsmiljoudvalget = $_POST['Arbejdsmiljoudvalget'];
} else {
    $Arbejdsmiljoudvalget =0;
}
if (isset($_POST['Boligpolitisk'])){
    $Boligpolitisk = $_POST['Boligpolitisk'];
} else {
    $Boligpolitisk =0;
}

if (isset($_POST['Dove'])){
    $Dove = $_POST['Dove'];
} else {
    $Dove =0;
}

if (isset($_POST['Energi'])){
    $Energi = $_POST['Energi'];
} else {
    $Energi =0;
}

?>
```

Comment: You mean you had to repeat the entire code 50 times or you have to  apply the if else condition to 50 different variables?

Comment: isset($_POST['Arbejdsmiljoudvalget'])?$Arbejdsmiljoudvalget = $_POST['Arbejdsmiljoudvalget'] : $Arbejdsmiljoudvalget= 0;
echo $Arbejdsmiljoudvalget;

Comment: Yes, there are more neat ways, but it's also taste. I would put default values in a hash.

Comment: create a function to do it. Call the function in the different places you need it

Comment: Try extract($_POST);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650446/php-switch-case-gets-variables-and-switch-case-gets-variables-values/16650475#16650475 similar to this question

Comment: JT70, this whole thing you are doing, only makes sense if you need the default values. Otherwise you can use the POST variables directly. Akkurat? :)

Comment: I mean I had to apply the if else condition to 50 different variables.

Comment: @cartina `extract` is great, but he will have a hell of a time trying to validate the inputs, as extracted vars are not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$list = array( 'Arbejdsmiljoudvalget', 'Boligpolitisk' );
foreach( $list as $param ){
     if( isset( $_POST[ $param ] ) ){
         $$param = $_POST[ $param ];
         continue;
     }
     $$param = 0;
}
```

The extra dollar in `$$param` creates a variable with the name stored in `$param`.
For eg, its the same as doing:

```
$Arbejdsmiljoudvalget = 'somevalue';
```

Comment: This one did it. :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since you know all names of post variables before running any script, you can create array of these names:

```
$names = [
     'Arbejdsmiljoudvalget',
     'Boligpolitisk',
     ...
];
```

Than loop that array and check if that name is in POST array:

```
foreach ($names as $name) {
    ${$name} = isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : 0;
}
```

But I think it's bad idea to have lots of variables. Better add them to array and than use like `$values['Arbejdsmiljoudvalget']`

Answer (score 4):

HankyPanky solution is nice, but what you ask for is a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct:

Some suggested to do the `extract()` on the `$_POST` array, but this is unsafe as allows overriding any internal variable. Same goes for looping over the `$_POST` array directly, but this is wrong too for the same reason. You'll have to either filter out anything but whitelisted variables from `$_POST` before extraction, either have a whitelist like this and loop through it:

```
<?php 
    $dict = array(
        'Arbejdsmiljoudvalget',
        'Boligpolitisk',
        'Dove',
        'Energi',
        // ...
    );


foreach ($dict as $term) {
    if (isset($_POST[$term])){
        ${$term} = $_POST[$term];
        continue;
    }
    ${$term} = 0;
}
```

Note there are much better ways to extract POST data than doing it by hand like that.

Comment: And if you need different initializations for each variable, you can put a key-value thing in the dict instead. If some variables need something else than `0`, I mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    if ( isset($value) ) {
        ${$key} = $value;
    }
    else {
        ${$key} = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

## Edit:

To make my original suggestion use Justinas note for using `$values` array instead of just creating 50 variables (also wont allow overwrite of other variables, like `$isAdmin` or such (as Sergey Telshevsky commented to my first suggestion)).
Also you don't have to determine every single value in a dictionary and loop the `$dict` array, so here is an example:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $values[$key] = ( isset($value) ? $value : 0 );
}
```

This will loop every posted value and check if `isset()`, otherwise will give it a value of 0.
Then you use the posted values like:

```
print "Thank you {$values['Name']} for submitting the form.<br/>" . PHP_EOL;
print "Your energy consumption {$values['Energi']}<br/>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Though this looks clean and easy, this is bad as it allows to override any variable. I would simply submit `isAdmin` as a POST var and it can break things.

Comment: Thats true, wouldn't necessary recommend using this in production enviroment. Would be much more safe to determine posted values in an array, and then use foreach for that array instead, like you just suggested.

Comment: Though, you may filter out anything but viable vars from `$_POST` first and then do the looping